# Should I run node-cron as part of the nodejs api server or as another node server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cron, node-cron

I have the following node api server to which I've added a `node-cron` job to periodically send emails to some users once per day. The code is working, however, I was wondering if I'll get myself into some performance issues.

**Would it be better to have the cron job as part of another server?**

**How is the cron job working behind the scenes? Would the `async` keyword help it?**

**Are there any drawbacks to the way I've implemented it now? Could it be that the cron job takes too long and the web requests will have issues?**

```
    const express = require('express');
    const cron = require("node-cron");
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const connectDB = require('./config/db');

    const app = express();

    // Connect to database
    connectDB();

    // Schedule tasks to be run on the server
    // second(optional) minute hour dayOfMonth month dayOfWeek
    cron.schedule('10 17 * * *', () => {
      // get some users from the database and send them emails
    });

    ...(other node api server stuff)

    const server = app.listen(
      PORT,
      console.log(
        `Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold
      )
    );
```